# Converting to cylindrical coordinates Calculus 3

Tags: integration, cylindrical-coordinates

I understanding converting to cylindrical coordinates, but specifically converting my $f(x,y,z)$ in this problem is difficult.

Evaluate $\iiint_R \left(x^4 + 2x^2y^2+y^4\right)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where $R$ is cylindrical solid $x^2+y^2 \le 25$ and $0\le z\le 1/\pi$.

I can't figure out how to convert $f$ to be in polar/cylindrical

Comment: $15625/3$ Was my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2$

Comment: I am such a dummy,  haha.  Thank you!